# Is $\log (e^n+n^e) =n$ for $n\geq15$ or for large $n$?

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods, approximation, integers

I have tried [some calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+log+(e%5En%2Bn%5Ee),+n%3D10+to+20n=15) for this formula $\log (e^n+n^e) $ i found that is closed to integer from $n=15$ which is $n$ , or probably to conjecture that $\log (e^n+n^e) $ could be integer and close to $n$  from $n=15$.

> > **My question here is**:
> >     Is $\log (e^n+n^e)  =n$  for  $n\geq15$ with $\log$ is natural logarithm?

Comment: It is close to $n$ since $e^n$ grows much faster than n^e.

Comment: You can forget the equality because $\ln(e^n+n^e)=n$ is equivalent with $e^n+n^e=e^n$... You could say $\approx$ instead of $=$

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$\log(e^n+n^e) > \log(e^n)=n.$$

Comment: for same answer (+1)

Comment: @gimusi Was going to say the same to you.

Comment: I've lost some seonds to eliminate the parenthesis from $\log e^n$ :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that since $\log$ function in **strictly monotonic increasing**

$$x>y \iff \log x > \log y$$

and since

$$e^n+n^e>e^n \implies \log (e^n+n^e)>\log e^n=n$$

> $$\implies \log (e^n+n^e)>n$$

What is true is that for $n\to\infty$

$$\log (e^n+n^e)\sim n$$

notably we say that for n large $\log (e^n+n^e)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $n$ in the sense that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\log (e^n+n^e)}{n}=1$$

Comment: Then the formula is integer for large n enough

Comment: @zeraouliarafik we say that for n large $\log (e^n+n^e)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $n$ in the sense that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\log (e^n+n^e)}{n}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

No since that would imply that
$$
e^n+n^e=e^n\implies n^e=0
$$
a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^n \lt e^n + n^e \lt e^{n+1}$ for $n > 0$ (proof left as an exercise), $n \lt \ln (e^n + n^e) \lt n + 1$, so the logarithm will *never* equal an integer (because it's always stuck between two of them). For sufficiently large $n$, it will get *arbitrarily close* to equalling $n$. So it will never be exactly equal, but for any positive value $\epsilon > 0$ you can make the difference smaller than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor, $$\ln(e^n+n^e)=n+\ln(1+n^ee^{-n})=n+n^ee^{-n}-\frac12(n^ee^{-n})^2\pm\dots.$$ For large $n$, $n^ee^{-n}$ and thus the fractional part of the expression will be small and rapidly falling.

For `double` floating point accuracy the fractional term will be too small to influence the mantissa if the relative error is smaller than the machine epsilon,
$$
n^{e-1}e^{-n}\le 2^{-53}\iff -\frac{n}{e-1}e^{-\frac{n}{e-1}}\ge-\frac{2^{-53/(e-1)}}{e-1}
$$
which with the Lambert-W function gives 
$$
n\ge -(e-1)W_{-1}\left(-\frac{2^{-53/(e-1)}}{e-1}\right)=43.2078896438...
$$
Thus indeed for $n\ge44$ the numerical result in `double` precision floating point will be $n$.

```
 n    ln(e^n+n^e)

37   37.0000000000015631940186722
38   38.0000000000006181721801113
39   39.0000000000002415845301584
40   40.0000000000000994759830064
41   41.0000000000000355271367880
42   42.0000000000000142108547152
43   43.0000000000000071054273576
44   44.0000000000000000000000000
```